# How to get Mouse Position as pixel number in the text boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, mouse-position

I am working on real-time video processing project.

During the real-time video i need to get mouse position when left clicked. To do that i have one button to send mouse position to text boxes. To see position of the cursor, i have two text boxes named as txt4 and txt5 for X and Y position seperately.

I have written the given code as shown the below. When i click the button it shows the current postion of the mouse (actually it is the position of the button) but then when i do left click position of the mouse is not shown in the text boxes. Position is shown when i press "Enter" while button is clicked.

What is wrong? and How can i correct it?

```
    private void btnCursor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (device.IsRunning)
        {
            
            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            txt4.Text = string.Format("x={0:0000}", Cursor.Position.X);
            txt5.Text = string.Format("y={0:0000}", Cursor.Position.Y);
        }
    }
    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Click>0)
        {
            txt4.Text = MousePosition.X.ToString();
            txt5.Text = MousePosition.Y.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I tried to get mouse position when i do left click.

What i get is mouse position when i pressed "Enter" instead of left clicked.

I have error in line "if(e.Click>0)".

Comment: "I have error in line `if(e.Click>0)`."  Always tell us the error.  Try using a mouse button instead:  `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)`

Comment: I edited the line as `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)` , there is no error but i could not still get the cursor point in the text boxes.
Should i add any button, box or something to Designer.

Comment: Are you moving the mouse when you do that?  Maybe try the same code in the MouseDown event.

Comment: It is written 0 references. I think i need to add button or something like that. What do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know what `0 references` means.  Make sure your events are subscribed.

Comment: Do you think i need tiptool, button or something ?

Comment: You don't need anything to make this work, except subscribe to the event.  If you haven't subscribed to the event, add this to your form's constructor: `panel1.MouseMove += panel1_MouseMove;`

Comment: I did it after choosing mousedown for picbox. Thanks a lot.